# Use IN operator along with NOT LIKE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am having a list of strings (1000+) that includes the wild card characters along with it.

```
i.e. abc%, xyz%, lop%.....
```

I want to fetch data from another table where we don't have the matching strings.

```
select * from table 
where pattern not like 'abc%'
and pattern not like  'xyz%'
and pattern not like 'lop%'
.......
```

The above query works when we have a limited set of wild card matching in where clause. But I am having
1000+ patterns to exclude. I got a `stack` error when I tried to add all the strings in the where clause. To overcome this issue, I tried to create a temp table and then tried to join it with my table.

```
    create table #temp (str varchar(200))
    insert into #temp values('abc%')
    .....
```

I want to fetch the records from my table where we don't have the above pattern (temp table).

Answer (score 0):

You can first find those that have a matching row in #temp and then select those that do not belong to that set:

```
select *
from yourtable y
where y.pattern not in (
   select y2.pattern
   from yourtable y2
     join #temp p on y2.pattern like p.str
)
```